# How to find a parent class from a child class and then find another child class from it?

Tags: javascript, css

I have multiple  tags that looks like this:

```
<div class="A">
  <div class="B1">...</div>
     <div class="C1">Hello World!</div>
     <div class="C2">World Hello!</div>
     <div class="C3">Hello</div> // Red text
  <div class="B2">Click Me!</div>
</div>

<div class="A">
  <div class="B1">...</div>
     <div class="C1">Hello World!</div>
     <div class="C2">World Hello!</div>
     <div class="C3">Hello</div> // Black text
  <div class="B2">Click Me!</div>
</div>
```

How can I select Class A containing the word "Hello" in red

and click on its child class B2.

I have been suffering for a week because this is so difficult.

How can I do this? Please help me sir TT

Comment: Technical terms matter a great deal here: in JS, a `class` is a very particular thing (namely, a modern syntax for working with object prototype chains without having to think about prototype chaining), and has nothing to do with the HTML `class="..."` attribute. What it sounds like you're asking about is finding the [parent node](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/parentNode) for some DOM element, and that parent's [child nodes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/childNodes).

Comment: Can you please differentiate between the expected user input and what the script is supposed to do? Does the user have to press on the red text Hello? What is the script supposed to do then?

Comment: What have you tried and what specifically goes wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this function to find parent element with a specific selector:

```
function findParent(el, selector)
{
  if (!el)
    return null;

  return el.matches && el.matches(selector) ? el : findParent(el.parentNode, selector);
}
```

From there you can use `parent_element.querySelector(".B2")` to find it's specific child.

Example:

```js
function findParent(el, selector)
{
  if (!el)
    return null;

  return el.matches && el.matches(selector) ? el : findParent(el.parentNode, selector);
}


const a = document.querySelectorAll(".A");

for(let i = 0; i < a.length; i++)
{
  a[i].querySelector(".C3").addEventListener("click", e =>
  {
    const b2 = findParent(e.target, ".A").querySelector(".B2")
    b2.click();
    console.log(".B2 clicked", b2);
  });
  a[i].querySelector(".B2").addEventListener("click", e => e.target.classList.toggle("clicked"));
}
```

```css
.A:first-child .C3
{
  color: red;
}

.B2.clicked
{
  background-color: lightblue;
}

.C3
{
  cursor: pointer;
  user-select: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="A">
  <div class="B1">...</div>
     <div class="C1">Hello World!</div>
     <div class="C2">World Hello!</div>
     <div class="C3">Hello, click me // Red text</div>
  <div class="B2">Click Me!</div>
</div>

<div class="A">
  <div class="B1">...</div>
     <div class="C1">Hello World!</div>
     <div class="C2">World Hello!</div>
     <div class="C3">Hello, click me // Black text</div>
  <div class="B2">Click Me!</div>
</div>
```